# R - socketConnection

Tags: r

I am a complete newbie when it comes to socket connection, and i am trying to learn how to use them in R. I am trying to follow the example in the R documentation for "connections".

However, when run the following command in Rstudio (running R 3.0):

```
con1 <- socketConnection(port = 6011, server = TRUE)
```

the application goes into an infinite loop, where i have to press the stop button to get out. As a results i can not continue to the next line of the example

```
writeLines(LETTERS, con1)
close(con1)
```

Can someone shed some light to what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The example that you're trying to execute requires two R processes.  The code that you show will block (as you've seen) until another process connects to it, specifying the same port:

```
con2 <- socketConnection(Sys.info()["nodename"], port = 6011)
```

Note that for this code to work, you must execute it on the same machine as the first process, otherwise it will throw an error.  Once the second process executes, the first process will *unblock*, returning a `socketConnection` object, and you can then write data to it which can be read by the second process.

Note that the example from the `socketConnection` man page is not run when you execute `example(socketConnection)`.  If it was, it would hang your R session as you've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Lalas, I'm also trying to do what you are trying to do as a complete know-nothing to sockets. `tdsmith` in the `#R` freenode chatroom gave me the right advice: use `telnet`.

---

So, terminal window 1:

```
R
s = socketConnection(port=12345, server=T)
```

`R` should be hanging now (waiting for someone to talk to it).

Now open another terminal window and type:

```
telnet localhost 12345
```

Go back to window 1. You'll see `R` is no longer hanging. Good! So now type (in same window 1):

```
readChar(s,3)
```

Return to window 2, the `telnet` window. Type:

```
Lalas wins at life.
```

What you'll see in window 1 is that text entered somewhere beyond the confines of window 1, has entered window 1.

```
Lal
```

Unfortunately `readChar` was expecting a shorter message, so you didn't get the whole thing. Try `readChar(s,6)` again and you'll hear

```
as win
```

. You'll notice that `readChar(s,1)` hears letters that seem to have been "hanging there" (where?). Weird. But clearly this is an annoying way to listen, having to pre-specify the message length!

---

Try `readLines(s)` which doesn't need the specification; it waits for an <kbd>EOL</kbd> character.

Back to window 2, the telnet window:

```
Money
that's what I want
that's what I waaaaaaaant
```

The only way I could figure to get `readLines(s)` to hear me was by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>'ing in `telnet` to get a prompt and then `close`ing. `R` won't hear all these newlines (even if you type `\r\n` etc), but once the connection is closed you'll get each line in window 1.

---

Now this is using more help from `ernst` in the same freenode room. Instead of using `telnet` this time used `nc localhost 12345`. Netcat can hear and speak, and behaves more expectedly in that I can send <kbd>EOL</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Close and reopen window 1's socket connection `s = socketConnection(port=12345,server=T)`. Close `telnet` in window 2 and type instead `nc localhost 12345`. Now type messages on either side and they can be received by each other.

window 1:

```
cat( rpois(1e2, 20), file=s)
readLines(s)
```

window 2 (should have already heard some random numbers):

```
Lalas
wins
at
life.
{{control D}}
```

window 1 should have now received the message.